# Git: Converging branches to a single commit object

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Say I currently have the following in git:

```
master
  O
  |
  o  <-- commit objects on master branch
  |   
  o -- O  <-- new branch: featureX
       |
       o  <-- commit objects on the featureX
       |
       o
```

So I started with the `master` branch and after two commits, I branched to `featureX`.

Now, after 2 commits on `featureX`, I want to converge it with `master` and continue work on `master` from the last commit on `featureX`.

This means that I don't want to merge the files between `master` and `featureX` but transferring all the commits done on `featureX` to `master` and continue working on `master` from the last commit that was done on `featureX`.

Basically, something like this:

```
master
  O
  |
  o  <-- commit objects on master branch
  |   
  o -- O  <-- new branch: featureX
       |
       o  <-- commit objects on the featureX
       |
  o -- o  <-- move everything back to master
  |
  o  <--continue working on master
```

**What are the steps I need to follow in order to this?**

Note that I do not want to merge any files together...just overwrite the stuff on `master`.  You can also assume that no work has been done on `master` while working on `featureX`.

Comment: The key thing that explains the answer that you got is that your ascii art history, though not drawn as such, is strictly linear. The commits don't know anything about branches, they just know who their parent is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no other work has been done on master since branching for featureX:

```
git checkout master
git merge featureX
```

This will be a "fast-forward" merge that should do what you want. After the above, you can:

```
git branch -d featureX
```

to delete the old branch.

Comment: `git checkout master; git reset featureX` would also work and would never do a merge

Comment: But won't a `merge` try to merge the files together?  I want to completely overwrite the files on `master`

Comment: @Andreas Grech: git only has to look at the files when there are changes to files on two diverging branches. As there are no further commits on you master branch it hasn't diverged from where featureX was branch from. There are no changes to merge, so no conflicts, so nothing to do at a file level. As Greg says, it will be a fast-forward merge where your master branch moves forward to where featureX is now. If you have a relatively recent git you can - for peace of mind - do `git merge --ff-only featureX` to make sure the merge only happens if it reall is a fast-forward.

Comment: Greg, Dan and Charles, thank you for your responses; all were of help to me.